# MySQL Connection fails when trying to connect

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database on C#, and my code have been working perfectly  since I started , but sometimes know is giving me this error like, every 2 days, sometimes work sometimes don't, I have 2 DB's on different servers and when I try to connect to the second server it works every time, whats wrong

this is the error

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified
>   MySQL hosts."

and this is my code

```
 MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        conn_string.Server = Conexion.Server;
        conn_string.Port = Conexion.PORT;
        conn_string.UserID = Conexion.UID;
        conn_string.Password = Conexion.PASSWORD;
        conn_string.Database = Conexion.Database;
        MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());
        SqlCon.Open();
        if (SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel_Con.Text = "Conectado";
            toolStripStatusLabel_Con.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            SqlCon.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel_Con.Text = "Desconectado";
            toolStripStatusLabel_Con.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            SqlCon.Close();
        }
```

Comment: How large is the database.  It may be taking longer to connect on a very large database.

Comment: @jdweng, the DB i'm using has , 15 tables and only three of them has data not more than 200 rows at least between those three, so i dont think thats the problem tho.. the other db has more than 1000 rows and 3 tables.